# Maven to include sibling project's binary as part of packaging

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jnlp

I have the following maven project structure,

```
parent
|
|-web
|-ui-jnlp
```

I want the ui-jnlp.jar to be part of web.war's WEB-INF/jnlp folder. Please note that not part of WEB-INF/lib.

How it is possible, as part of maven build? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you should use a different plugin to create your jnlp like this: http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use this for packaging JNLP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)
to get the jar created by your child build into your target folder in your parent build, then it can be part of your parent package.
It means you have to build your child first obviously, and it has to be built using 'install'.